# How to implement OAuth2 flow in Single Page Applications (Angular2 + Rails4)

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-page-application

I am wondering which OAuth2 flow best suit the SPA scenario. The front-end is angular and the backend is rails.

I think the authorization code grant type is the most adequate for this scenario but I am not sure how to handle the redirection when the user grants access to my application. That redirection breaks the SPA spirit to keep the user in the same page.

Thanks

EDIT (Added information):

Let me be more precise. Particularly I am trying to integrate google calendar into my app using this flow https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer. I am facing various problems, most of them because I have an angular SPA.

My first problem is how to handle the authorization endpoint. Up to now, I have devise and endpoint called `/google_auth` that will check whether the current user has authorized the app or not. If not, I will respond with a json body that has the authorization_uri. Here comes the first problem, how does the front-end show the authorization dialog. If I call `window.open` the browser will block it because it thinks its a popup. If I change the current window location it will leave my app and I don't want this.

The second problem appears when the user authorize my app in the authorization window presented by google. Here, google will send a request with the authorization code to the redirect uri callback previously defined. As I am using JWT token for authentication, in this request I lose which user has granted me authorization so I can't associate the refresh token to the user. How can I handle this? I am thinking I can use the `state`  parameter to forward the JWT token, but I am no sure this is secure enough

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed, but don't forget why this happens.

The whole point is that the user does not enter their password in an unknown application and most won't. When people see the login page from Facebook for example, they trust that and are cool with it. A random form asking them for their password is not cool and can lead to them being hacked which is why everyone who is concerned with security will simply leave that insecure website and move on.

My suggestion is to stick with the flow which makes sense. Once the user is authenticated and gives your app access, they will be sent back to your app and there you can get the token and use it to do further work so you are basically back in the SPA flow. It's just that your flow now has 2 steps, that's all.

Comment: I understand your suggestions. I have updated my question though giving more details about which are my specific problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have 2 UI options: open the authorization page in the same window thus unloading your SPA, or in a pop-up, thus having risk of it being blocked. Unless the frontend app's state is too large, you may store essential app's state, go through authorization, and reload the app restoring the state. The state may be stored in browser's localStorage, in the redirect URL (if protocol allows variable part) or on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is in public space, follow the authorization based flow if in enterprise then either the first option of password grant flow is also ok.